How to clear a warning on a Windows Storage Space Pool
For some reason I have a Windows Storage Space storage pool on Windows Server 2019 showing as warning / degraded, even though all the disks, virtual disks and volumes are fine and showing no warning. SMART data doesn't show any problem on any of the disks either. The volume has hardly any data and was recently created. All the disks are SAS SSD, used but in a good state.
See screenshot here 1
Powershell shows no reason for the storage pool to be degraded and shows the underlying physical disks and virtual disks as healthy:
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-StoragePool -FriendlyName SASSSDSP |  format-list -Property FriendlyName,HealthStatus,IsReadOnly,OperationalStatus,OtherOperationalStatusDescription,ReadOnlyReason

FriendlyName                      : SASSSDSP
HealthStatus                      : Warning
IsReadOnly                        : False
OperationalStatus                 : Degraded
OtherOperationalStatusDescription : 
ReadOnlyReason                    : None

PS C:\Windows\system32> get-StoragePool -FriendlyName SASSSDSP | Get-PhysicalDisk | Format-Table -Property DeviceId,SlotNumber,FriendlyName,MediaType,OperationalStatus,healthStatus,OperationalDetails

DeviceId SlotNumber FriendlyName             MediaType OperationalStatus HealthStatus OperationalDetails
-------- ---------- ------------             --------- ----------------- ------------ ------------------
4                 0 NETAPP X357_SLNGE3T8ATE  SSD       OK                Healthy                        
7                 3 SanDisk DDYE3840S5xnNMRI SSD       OK                Healthy                        
9                 5 NETAPP X356_S163A3T8ATE  SSD       OK                Healthy                        
6                 2 NETAPP X356_S163A3T8ATE  SSD       OK                Healthy                        
8                 4 NETAPP X357_S16433T8ATE  SSD       OK                Healthy                        
11                7 NETAPP X357_S16433T8ATE  SSD       OK                Healthy                        
5                 1 NETAPP X357_S16433T8ATE  SSD       OK                Healthy                        
10                6 NETAPP X357_S16433T8ATE  SSD       OK                Healthy                        

PS C:\Windows\system32> get-StoragePool -FriendlyName SASSSDSP | Get-virtualDisk

FriendlyName ResiliencySettingName FaultDomainRedundancy OperationalStatus HealthStatus  Size FootprintOnPool StorageEfficiency
------------ --------------------- --------------------- ----------------- ------------  ---- --------------- -----------------
SASSSDVD     Simple                0                     OK                Healthy      25 TB           25 TB           100.00%

I don't like leaving something in a degraded state when it is not degraded as I monitor the health status of the storage pool, physical and virtual disks and want to get an alert when it becomes actually degraded. What can I do to clear this degraded status?
